# ¿Cómo hago una lista circular doblemente enlazada usando objetos?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

He hecho una lista circular doblemente enlazada usando objetos, pero al llegar al ultimo nodo no me permite seguir avanzando, como podría solucionarlo?

Tengo entendido que en las listas circulares los nodos no son nulos y se puede avanzar continuamente por lo cual no entiendo por que cuando llego al ultimo nodo no regresa al primero, cualquier sugerencia o recomendación la apreciaría mucho.

agrego el código:

Clase skyns

```
 public class skyns {
    private String imagen;
 
    public skyns(String imagen) {
        super();
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }
    
    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }
    
    public void setImagen(String imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    } 
    
    }
```

clase Nodo

```
 public class Nodo {
        public skyns informacion; 
        public Nodo anterior;
        public Nodo siguiente;
        
        public Nodo getAnterior() {
            return anterior;
        }
        public void setAnterior(Nodo anterior) {
            this.anterior = anterior;
        }
        public Nodo getSiguiente() {
            return siguiente;
        }
        public void setSiguiente(Nodo siguiente) {
            this.siguiente = siguiente;
        }
        public skyns getInformacion() {
            return informacion;
        }
        public void setInformacion(skyns informacion) {
            this.informacion = informacion;
        }
    }
```

clase listacircular

```
public class listacircular {
    private Nodo ultimo;
    private Nodo primero;
    private int size;
     
    //Constructor
    public listacircular() {
        ultimo = null;
        primero = null;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }
 
       //Metodos
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.ultimo == null && this.primero == null;
    }
    
       //Agregar elemento

    public void addElement(skyns v) {
        Nodo nuevo = new Nodo();
        nuevo.setInformacion(v);
        if(primero ==null) {
            primero = nuevo;
            ultimo = primero;
        }else {
            Nodo temporal = ultimo;
            ultimo = nuevo;
            ultimo.setAnterior(temporal);
            temporal.setSiguiente(nuevo);
        }
    }
    
    
    public Nodo primero() {
        return primero;
    }
}
```

Clase prueba (interfaz grafica)

public class prueba {

```
public JFrame frame;
private Nodo nodo;

JLabel lblnodo = new JLabel();
public prueba(Nodo primero) {
    this.nodo = primero;
    initialize();
    establecerValor();
}


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    
    
    lblnodo.setBounds(107, 95, 178, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblnodo);
    
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("avanzar");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            
                if( nodo.getSiguiente() != null) {
                    nodo = nodo.getSiguiente();
                    establecerValor();
                }
                    
            
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(146, 170, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
}
public void establecerValor() {
    lblnodo.setText(nodo.getInformacion().getImagen());
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como es una lista circular, el ultimo nodo debe si o si apuntar al primero...

En tu codigo, nunca seteas en la clase nodo setSiguiente para el nuevo ultimo.. si lo hiciste, para el ultimo que acabas de sacar apuntando al nuevo.... Entonces no hay forma de ir al proximo nunca...

```
public void addElement(skyns v) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo.setInformacion(v);
    if(primero ==null) {
        primero = nuevo;
        ultimo = primero;
    }else {
        Nodo temporal = ultimo;
        ultimo = nuevo;
        ultimo.setAnterior(temporal);
        temporal.setSiguiente(nuevo);
        //falta setearle a ultimo, para que apunte al primero!
        ultimo.setSiguiente(primero);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @NicolasD de nada, pero recuerda aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron (en todas las preguntas que hiciste)